# Wait for backend response to update page

Tags: angular, spring-boot, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working on Angular 6 - Spring Boot application. Frontend - backend communication is based on REST requests. For example:

```
 @GetMapping("/all")
 @ResponseBody
 public Iterable<ProductDto> getAllProducts(){
    return productService.getAllProducts();
 }

 @PostMapping("/add")
 public ProductDto addProduct(@Valid @RequestBody ProductDto productDto){
     return productService.addProduct(productDto);
 }
```

I'm populating simple HTML table by first request, using this method to invoke REST

```
populateProductTable() {    
    this.products = new Array<Product>();
    this.http.get<Product[]>('http://localhost:8080/product/all').subscribe(data => {
      for(let x in data) {
        const product = new Product();

        product.name = data[x].name;
        product.categoryName = data[x].categoryName;
        product.kcal = data[x].kcal    
        product.protein = data[x].protein
        product.fat = data[x].fat
        product.carb = data[x].carb    

        this.products.push(product);
      }
    });
  }
```

And to add item via POST:

```
addProduct() {    
    const product = new Product();

    product.name = this.productNameValue;
    product.categoryName = this.categoryValue;
    product.kcal = this.caloriesValue;
    product.protein = this.proteinValue;
    product.fat = this.fatValue;
    product.carb = this.carbsValue;

    let productJson = JSON.stringify(product);   
    let response;

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/product/add', productJson, options).subscribe(data => response = data);        

    do {
      this.resloveAfter1Second(this.populateProductTable());
      console.log(response);    
    } while(response == undefined);

  }

  resloveAfter1Second(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(x);
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

As you can imagine, I'm having troubles with updating my table. POST works, I got new `Product` stored in database, but probably becouse of some kind of delays, html is rendered before, so 1 per few requests need another page refresh to actually see new value in table. Thats why I tried simple `do-while` loop that is invoked as long as I dont have response. Unfortunatelly, this loop goes forever and soon enough crash my web browser. I bet there is better solution to that?

edit#
I'v added `Logger` into my Spring Boot Application, with using this without loop

```
this.resloveAfter3Second(this.populateProductTable());
  }

  resloveAfter3Second(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("resolving promise");
        resolve(x);
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

I'd expect logs like
-adding new product
-reading all products

but instead, few times I got
-reading all products
-adding new product

So it seems like my Angular app does GET before POST, but how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding you entirely, but  if you're trying to make sure to re-fetch the items after your post request succeeds, then your call to "populateProductTable" should be nested after the response of the POST call is received, like that:

```
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/product/add', productJson, options)
    .subscribe(data => { 
       populateProductTable();
       response = data; 
    });
```